# Vim Plugin to integrate programming language documentation

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I know there is a plugin named pydoc that integrates python documentation with vim. But is there a general plugin that integrates a chosen documentation with a chosen file extension.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no such plugin for *arbitrary* documentation (at least as far as I know), but there are many plugins for particular documentation sources.  Personally I'm using [vim-ref](https://github.com/thinca/vim-ref) (which supports Clojure, Erlang, UNIX man, perldoc, PHP manual, pydoc, and Ruby's ReFe), and [info](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=21) (for GNU Info; this one is quite old but still better than many alternatives).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I do not want to limit myself to a specific plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[Vinfo](https://github.com/alx741/vinfo) is a Vim plugin that allows you to read
 [Info documentation files](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/)  right inside a
Vim session in a Vim-help fashioned way or from a shell just the way you normally use
 [Info](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info/info.html#Top)